# Windows 10 v. 1803 update issue, not resolved by Update Troubleshooter

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, updates

For a few weeks, Windows Update has been failing with error 0x80070426 in the Event Log. Despite the warning `Your device is missing important security and quality fixes`, no update KB item is listed.

[image: Windows Update dialog]

The Windows Update Repair tool finishes with apparent success, but despite repeated attempts, it has not resolved the issue. After running repair, a search for updates produces the dialog above.

[image: Update Repair dialog]

The OS is Windows 10 Home version 1803, build 17134.112, and the last updates listed in History are `KB4100347: Intel microcode updates`, installed 9/17/2018, and `KB4456655: Servicing stack update for Windows 10, version 1803`, installed 9/11/2018. History shows no recent pending or failed update.

Comment: Have you tried to download, and manually install the current cumulative update?  The servicing stack update is required for the most recent cumulative updates, so that isn't the problem, although it is weird that it was installed before the appropriate cumulative update was installed (which tells me it hasn't been working for months).  It has not been weeks, we are talking months, 17134.112 is **months old**

Comment: "Could the issue be caused by one of these updates? Has anyone experienced a similar issue since installing them?" - **Your issue is unique to your system, while other people might have the same issue, the updates work for millions of people.  Let me be clear, the problem, is your installation**

Comment: @Ramhound, since you state update has not been working for months, the simplest answer, for me, would be to wait for the next cumulative update (to be released in October, I think) and reinstall from the new ISO.

Comment: Ramound's advice is beneficial, as always.  Personally, if you are already considering doing a full wipe-and-reload next month, I would go ahead and try Shawn Brink's batch file to completely reset your Windows Update configuration:  [Reset Windows Update in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/24742-reset-windows-update-windows-10-a.html)

Comment: June 12 was when .112 was released, so it’s been, more than 60 days.  However, whatever is blocking the updates, could end up blocking the feature update.  So you should try manually installing the current cumulative update.

Answer (score 0):

Installing Windows 10 from USB to replace v. 1803 with v. 1809 resolved the update issue.

**However**, there were two issues I experienced, and a number of others which have [prompted Microsoft to remove the initial Windows 10 v. 1809 update files](https://www.pcworld.com/article/3311977/windows/microsoft-pulls-windows-10-october-2018-update-file-deletion.html). In fact, Microsfoft state, “[If you have manually downloaded the Windows 10 October 2018 Update installation media, please don’t install it and wait until new media is available.](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-10-october-update-is-no-longer-being/62e8e6b4-0089-41c2-a104-5a5a768a48f6)"

The issues I faced was *complete* deletion of images used for background screens (even from Windows.old) and the failure of Windows Notifications to be displayed. Since I had made a disk image prior to updating, I was able to recover lost files. It took considerable time to find the fix for the Action Center.

[image: Fix Notifications for Windows 10 v. 1809]

In Settings | Privacy | Background apps, turn *On* `Let apps run in the background`, then reboot for the change to take effect.

Normally, I would *not* answer my own question, but because of the issues with Windows 10 v. 1809, I'm doing so to let others know of the issue with the first release and of the *undocumented* change to Notifications and the fix for that.